# Ask him for photos of/ Ask him to send you photos of his

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

I know it's correct to say:
*"Ask him to send you photos of his vintage car collection."*

But is it also correct to say:
*"Ask him for photos of his vintage car collection."*

And lastly, which one would a native speaker say?

Answer (score 3):

Both the sentences are correct. In the first one, the verb is acting as an infinitive, whereas in the second sentence, we have dropped the verb altogether and opted for a preposition. Many such verbs are dropped or modified to choose a preposition.

Examples:

> Ask them to give/provide you with the receipt.
>
> Ask them for the receipt.

> You should have asked him to help you.
>
> You should have asked for his help.

Answer (score 1):

Just happened upon this, not an expert.  But, to my "native speaker" ears, BOTH seem equally correct, and BOTH would be said by a native speaker.

I think most people would say the latter -- just because it's shorter.  The first is has that infinitive ("to send") and I'm not very sure it is 100% gramatically correct -- should it be "to send to you"?  If so, it's getting awkward.

Comment: Yeah either is fine! The first example is a little more explicit about the details of how you get the photos - it implies a method (the photos will be delivered, probably via email or on social media or something) and also an action (the person needs to actively send them, so it's like fulfilling a request or an order). So you might see that version in, say, a work setting.

Answer (score 0):

***If we are saying," Ask him for photos of " That means we are asking him to bring photos or send it .Both of the options are open. But if we mention 'send' that means he will not bring it. He will send it Via something or someone! In that case both of the sentences are right but that depends on how you want him to provide you the photos***